# Overview of topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

I found this picture in the internet:

[image]

Here: http://mathonline.wikidot.com/connected-and-disconnected-topological-spaces-review

And this one:

[image]

Here: https://finlotic.wordpress.com/topology-kundu-diagram/

These are good overviews which I would expand as I go along. Do you have anything similar to this?

Comment: This is definitely illuminating and fun... but/and not all the possible topological spaces' types arise often "in practice" (as opposed to being logically possible). So, from another side, it is at least equally useful to contemplate relations among naturally-occurring (meaning not necessarily in a point-set topology context) topological spaces that have varying properties. Topological vector spaces of functions (smooth? compactly supported? moderate growth? ...) provide a useful menagerie, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Tip: Counterexamples in Topology (Steen and Seebach) has some tables and diagrams like these for more advanced notions too. It's cheap (Dover edition) and nice if this is your kind of thing, though somewhat dated. At [$\pi$-base](https://topology.pi-base.org) you can look for more spaces to fill in your diagrams (it's mostly based off this book).